# tr "[1-9]" "['01'-'09']" not working properly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to cut only the date part from a `ls -lrth | grep TRACK` output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ins ins   0 Dec  3 00:00 TRACK_1_20121203_01010014.LOG
-rw-r--r-- 1 ins ins   0 Dec  3 00:00 TRACK_0_20121203_01010014.LOG
-rw-r--r-- 1 ins ins   0 Dec 13 15:10 TRACK_9_20121213_01010014.LOG
-rw-r--r-- 1 ins ins   0 Dec 13 15:10 TRACK_8_20121213_01010014.LOG
```

But, doing this:

```
ls -lrth | grep TRACK | tr "\t" " " | cut -d" " -f 9
```

only gives me the dates which are double digits and spaces for single digits:

```
13
13
```

So I tried something with `tr` command, to translate all single digit dates to double digits:

```
ls -lrth | grep TRACK | tr "\t" " " | tr "[1-9]" "['01'-'09']" |  cut -d" " -f 9
```

But it's giving some weird results, and evidently don't serve my purpose. Any ideas on how to get the correct output?

Answer (score 6):

Don't parse `ls` output.

`ls` is a tool for interactively looking at file information. Its output is formatted for humans and will cause bugs in scripts. Use `globs` or `find` instead. Understand why: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

I recommend this way :

If you want the date and the file path :

```
find . -name 'TRACK*' -printf '%a %p\n'
```

If you want only the date:

```
find . -name 'TRACK*' -printf '%a\n'
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try another approach with something like

```
find . -name 'TRACK*' -exec stat -c %y {} \; | sort
```

You can add something like `| cut -f1 -d' '` if you only need the date.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this does suffice:

```
ls -lhrt | grep TRACK | awk '{print $6, $7, $8}'
```

Answer (score 1):

that kind of substitution would be better handled through `sed`:

```
ls -lrth | grep TRACK | sed 's/ \+/ /g;s/ \([0-9]\) / 0\1 /g' | cut -d" " -f 7
```

Answer (score 1):

As already said, never parse the output of `ls`!

Since you only want the modification time, the command `date` has a cool option for that: option `-r` (`man date` for more info).

Hence, you probably want this instead of your line:

```
for i in TRACK*; do date -r "$i"; done
```

I don't know how you want the format of the date, so play with the options, e.g.,

```
for i in TRACK*; do date -r "$i" "+%D"; done
```

(the formats are in `man date`).

Comment: not all versions of `date` support the `-r` option. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stat` to get information about a file.

Also, `tr` only does one-to-one character translation.  It won't replace one-character sequences with two-character ones.